# C:\Windows\Servicing\LCU slowing down servers and workstations; mitigate automatically?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Increasingly, when I see a sluggish server, workstation, or laptop, I find on the order of 200,000 items in `C:/Windows/Servicing/LCU`.
That high a count makes for slow filesystems.

I understand it builds at every update.  Is there any way to mitigate this apart from manual or scripted methods?

Comment: There is no such folder. Do you mean `C:/Windows/Servicing/LCU` ? And which Windows version?

Comment: Thanks, and corrected yes.  So far on 10, 11, Server 2016, Server 2019.  Haven't on 2022 yet, but we haven't had many of those running a long time as of yet.

Comment: Does your server... etc Do they have SSD or M.2 NVMe because upgrading to an SSD is the best way to resolve file system speed issues.

Answer (score 2):

LCU refers to the Last Cumulative Update which is a backup folder
in case you may want to uninstall the last Cumulative Update.
This folder is usually located at `C:/Windows/Servicing/LCU`.

At least on my Windows 10, the LCU folder has the particularity
that it's owned by System and cannot be manipulated even by administrators.
However, by some Windows miracle, administrators do have
complete control on its sub-folders.
So, while the LCU folder cannot be deleted by administrators,
its sub-folders can be deleted.

Preventing the LCU folder from building up in the first place seems
impossible, as this action is built-into Windows Update and
there are no settings for this.

A command-line method for emptying it in a Command Prompt or PowerShell
that is Run as Administrator :

```
Dism exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

You may also use Explorer to remove the sub-folders of LCU. However,
I recommend leaving the most recent CU, to be able to roll it back
if it caused errors.
You may also create a PowerShell script that does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been clearing it by ROBOCOPY from a blank folder, multithreaded.  I'll have to compare its speed with that DISM, I did not know that it was doing that close to the same thing, and I'll think the DISM is safer.